# Tunneling ssh traffic to Linux server via multiple windows servers (2k8)

Tags: windows, linux, putty, tunnel, plink

I am looking for a solution to this problem:

1. At the end there are 3 different Linux servers (let's name them probe1,probe2,probe3)
2. There's a win2k8 gateway to access them via ssh (22) (let's name it probeGTW)
3. There's another win2k8 gateway which I have to use to access probeGTW (don't ask me...) (let's name it GTW)
4. Monitoring server (another win2k8) has unlimited access to GTW.
5. I need to be able to access probe1-3 directly from monitoring server to automate the monitoring process (need to run 'ps' command on Linux probes).

Is it possible with using just plink or any other similar solution that I could run as a service (so the requirement is for this to be a command-line tool)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the machines in the chain have an ssh (command line) client installed, you could just run that on each hop. So, assuming you have a command line ssh client on the original host you could run this:

```
ssh user@GTW -- ssh user@probeGTW -- ssh user@probe1 -- ps
```

You might want to enable agent forwarding for the authentication part on all the hosts involved.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, I'm currently only limited to plink.exe which is putty command-line tool - maybe you could suggest a windows ssh client that would work with your solution ? I'm working within corporate environment so some open-source/freeware stuff might not be appropriate...

Comment: I think this solution is apt. You could use PuTTY to initially connect to the linux box and from there run the ssh command.

Comment: Well, from what I can tell on its doc page, plink.exe would work precisely the same as ssh - although you might need to drop the `--`: http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.53b/htmldoc/Chapter7.html